# Ruby on Rails : get route using controller, action & param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, controller, action

I am quite new to RoR and I am looking for a way of getting a route for a given controller, action & param.

Something similar to url_for() but without the domain and protocol.

Lets say I have :

```
params = {"controller"=>"controller", "action"=>"edit", "project_id"=>"1"}
```

I need to get :

```
route = "/controller/edit/1"
```

It would be best if I do not have to manually build the route and if I don't need to split the result of url_for().

Does RoR natively support such a feature? It's probably an easy question, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use this versus using named URLs?

Comment: `my_action_my_controller_path(project_id: 1)` is the helper than will generate a path like you want (use `my_action_my_controller_url` instead if needed)

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yes! Thank you; that is exactly what I was looking for. I found more info about this helper : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Comment: @MrYoshiji Make it an answer so everyone can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the helper that will generate a path like you want:

```
edit_controller_path(project_id: 1)
```

You can use this Helper to generate the full path (including host) of the link:

```
edit_controller_url(project_id: 1)
```

Edit :
More info available at 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the following

```
link_to "Link Content", :controller => "my_controller", :action => "my_action", :project_id => 1
```

This will produce an `<a>` with a link to your controller/action.