# Rails - Find index, new, edit path from controller or instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have been DRYing up the code for a Rails project. Is it possible to find the index, new and edit path from the controller name or from the object/collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to search a little more to get the solution.

Answering this question myself and linking it to an existing SO question.

[Ruby on Rails : get route using controller, action & param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574179/ruby-on-rails-get-route-path-with-controller-action-param)