# How to get Rails path/url dinamically from a model/controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In Ruby-on-Rails you can get paths/urls with helper methods like `user_path(id)` for `UsersController#show` ([Official doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers)). That is easy **as long as** you know the model and action, [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574179/ruby-on-rails-get-route-using-controller-action-param).

But I would like to get a path for an arbitrary model like `MyModel` or Controller and action like `show`, where I do not know them a priori. How can I do it?

With Ruby `Object#send`, dynamical programming is always possible like the following, where I assume your app follows the Rails convention (Note that the following snippet is written in a way path helpers can be used anywhere in Rails, not limited in Views etc):

```rb
 # Suppose the model is expressed as a String instance mdl_name (like "User"),
 # ID is mdl_id, and the action is a Symbol instance my_action.
case my_action
when :index
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send(
    mdl_name.underscore.pluralize + '_path')
when :show
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send(
    mdl_name.underscore + '_path', mdl_id)
else
  # :new, :edit, ...
end
```

But this is not pretty at all. I suppose there is a bettr way?

Comment: have you tried `url_for(model)`?

Comment: @BroiSatse Oh, I didn't know the method. Its arguments like `controller` and `action` seem to work according to <https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html>  Would you like to compile it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `url_for` method, which is rails skeleton key for all routing. It can be used in a multitude of ways:

```
url_for({}) # current url
url_for(controller: 'user', action: :show, id: model.id) # with a hash
url_for(action: :index) # with a partial hash - it will use current controller (and all other current routing params)
url_for(user) # with a model - this is equivalent of user_path(user.id)
url_for([:admin, user]) # scoped model - equivalent of admin_user_path(user.id)
url_for(company, user) # nested routes, equivalent_of copmany_user_path(company.id, user.id)
```

and many many more. If this is still not enough, you can define your own dynamic routes using `resolve` in your routes file.

url_for is used all over the place in rails. it is used, among others by `link_to`, `button_to`, `form_for`, `redirect_to` etc - and all the options listed above can be used in places when url is expected:

```
link_to 'User', @user
redirect_to [:admin, user]
```

Comment: I confirm [`url_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html) works in Controllers and Views, ta. To add, it should be called as `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for` in other contexts. Also, I find the option `only_path: true` is handy (otherwise you may need specify a host).

Comment: @MasaSakano - I'd however strongly advise against using it in other contexts as it creates an awfully strong coupling. If you need it outside of the view or controller, generate it in a http-aware context and pass it as an argument - this will save you hours of future work.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. That makes sense. One point out of Controllers/Views where path helpers can be truly useful is in Rails Console and maybe in some *temporary* test scripts. Other than those, I agree with you!